# Repartitioning Google Analytics data based on publish date

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

I'm looking to repartition Google analytics data from stats date tables (the default export we get each day) to dated tables based on published date of each article URL (a custom dim we have). This is for more efficient querying by publish date by a BI dashboard that needs to calculate user counts on the fly for arbitrary date ranges.

So plan is to append data each day to the relevant publish dated tables. Just wondering if there is an easy way to do this or if I need to look though each stats date data for all the publish dates that had hits each day and then append one by one to relevant publish date tables?

Comment: We are waiting for a feature so we can run queries and write to partitioned tables based on an existing date column, as currently you need to write the destination tables partition date out in the API call. Stay tuned as soon will be much more easier than currently it is.

Comment: Yeah, just looked at one recent day and content from over 1000 separate publish dates was touched so that would be a separate append request for each one. I've tried to parallelize things like this before in bq and got concurrency rate limits so think this could start looking ugly.

Comment: And the costs will be high to query all data and repartition. I know it's like that today, but we wait for the feature to be launched, we asked so many times we need simpler ways to repartition a table based on existing date fields with one command and without full table scans.

Comment: you can subscribe to the issue tracker https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues/detail?id=611